# Is '->' a operator? What does it return?

Tags: scala

In Scala I can build a `Map` this way:

```
val map = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three")
```

But what does it do? The arguments should be evaluated, so `1 -> "one"` has a value. What's it?

I also noticed this expression returns true:

```
scala> 1 -> "one" == (1, "one")
res1: Boolean = true
```

So what's the difference?

Comment: There is **no operator** in Scala, everything is method (just with a weird name).

Comment: Eastsun> I think it's quite beneficial to view single-arity methods on objects as operators, especially when they are usually called as infix-operators.

Comment: When I say objects here, I of course mean instances of classes (sorry  for the confusion, too many damn keywords in Scala :P )

Comment: @Eastsun Not exactly, to be pedantic. Dot, assignment, comma, etc. are examples of operators that are not methods.

Comment: @ghik Dot and comma are delimiters; While assignment sometimes are alias of method, i.e. you can change the behavior of assignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It comes from the class `ArrowAssoc` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$$ArrowAssoc.html). Look in the object `Predef` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html) which contains all the pre-imported methods. There you should find the method `any2ArrowAssoc[A](x: A): ArrowAssoc[A]` which is the implicit conversion allowing the method `->` to be called on anything.

To elaborate on this answer, this means that the following code is implicit in your examples:

```
scala> 'a' -> 1 == (any2ArrowAssoc('a').->(1))
res0: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1):

In short it's just an extension method on `Pair` (or `Tuple2`) type. If you take a look at `Map` type in scala, you'' see that it consist of pairs or tuples of arity of 2. As i know it was defined specially for `Map` construction to denote `key value` association `key -> value`, but you can easily write `Map(("a", 1), ("b", 2))` which is equivalent to `Map("a" -> 1, "b"-> 2)`, just looks better. So `1 -> "one" == (1, "one")` is equals cause it's the same. In scala, `->` [is defined](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L249) as an implicit class in Predef object

Comment: `it's just an extension method on Pair` I guess you mean `extension method on any type T, that returns Pair[T, ...]`.

Comment: Yes you should edit the answer; as @senia said, it is _not_ and extension method on `Pair`/`Tuple2`; that is the _result_ of that method. It is defined on _any_ type by means of `any2ArrowAssoc`.

Answer (score 1):

From book "Programming in Scala" (http://booksites.artima.com/programming_in_scala_2ed):

The Scala compiler transforms a binary operation expression like `1 -> "Go to island."` into `(1).->("Go to island.")`.

Thus, when you say `1 -> "Go to island."`, you are actually calling a method named `->` on an integer with the value `1`, passing in a string with the value `"Go to island."`

This `->` method, which you can invoke on any object in a Scala program, returns a two-element tuple containing the key and value.

The Scala mechanism that allows you to invoke `->` on any object, implicit conversion.